# Getting metadata from Beats Music Application

Tags: android, metadata, beatsmusic

We  are developing application that collects data about tracks that user is currently playing in Android Beats Music application. How can we get metadata about the track that is currently playing (artist, track title, etc.). Does Beats Music broadcast such an info?

For example this two default messages for broadcast helps us to find that info in default Android player:

**com.android.music.metachanged**

**com.android.music.playstatechanged**

Do you have anything similar in Beats Music application ?

Answer (score 0):

We do not have this functionality available publicly, at this time.